# Using dplyr to get multiple max values of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
  Name    Variable1 Value1 Variable2 Value2
1 Michael         A      2      <NA>     <NA>
2 Michael         B      3      <NA>     <NA>
3 Michael      <NA>   <NA>         X       10
4    John         B      5      <NA>     <NA>
5    John         E      3      <NA>     <NA>
6    John      <NA>    <NA>        Y      20
7    John      <NA>    <NA>        Z      40
8    Paul         C     10      <NA>     <NA>
9    Paul         D      5      <NA>     <NA>
```

In all rows, there is either a Variable1/Value1 pair, or a Variable2/Value2 pair. 
I'm trying to use `dplyr` with a combination of `group_by` and `filter` functions  to generate a dataframe that has (1) only one row for each name and (2) the max-Value pairs for both 1 and 2.  In this case, my final table would look something like:

```
     Name Variable1 Value1 Variable2 Value2
1 Michael         B      3         X     10
2    John         B      5         Z     40
3    Paul         C     10      <NA>   <NA>
```

I can't seem to get the correct flow of grouping to execute this properly.  One solution I've thought of is to split the dataframe into two for each pair, filter, using `group_by` and `filter` on each separately, and then joining them back together based on Name, but I was wondering if anybody had a more straightforward solution to offer.  Maybe something with `summarise`?

Thank you!

EDIT: Corrected missing NA values in table.

Comment: `aggregate(df, by=list(Name), 
+           FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: In a `dplyr` method: `group_by(x, Name) %>% summarise_all(max)`. In `data.table`-speak: `x[,lapply(.SD, max),by="Name"]`.

Comment: These solutions don't seem to work -- both give me errors regarding dealing with factors, presumably because max doesn't work with the columns Variable1 and Variable2.  I want to be able to get the max of Value1 and Value2, and then get the associated Variable as well.

Comment: Are the missing value for Variable 2 in rows 4 and 5 blank, or NA?

Comment: They were meant to be NA.  Thanks!  Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df[is.na(df)] <- 0

df1 <-
  df %>%
  select(1:3)

df1_max <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value1 = max(Value1))

df2 <-
  df %>%
  select(c(1, 4:5))

df2_max <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value2 = max(Value2))

result <- left_join(
  left_join(df1_max, df1),
  left_join(df2_max, df2) %>%
    distinct()
) %>%
  select(c(1, 3, 2, 5, 4))

result[result == 0] <- NA
```

**Result:**

```
result

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name    Variable1 Value1 Variable2 Value2
  <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1 John    B              5 Z             40
2 Michael B              3 X             10
3 Paul    C             10 <NA>          NA
```

**Notes:**

- In data frames, the elements in a row are not independent from each other. So you shouldn't be able to dissociate them from each other. But this is what you are trying to do since the max value for `Variable1` and the max value for `Variable2` are not on the same row, yet you want your result to have the max for each (thus creating a row that does not exist in your original data frame). This is why I split your data frame into 2, then re-associated them with a join.
- The max of `NA` and a value is `NA` (we don't know what value `NA` is since it is missing, so we cannot know what the max is). Yet, you are considering `NA` to be inferior to any value. Since this is not how R works, I had to assign `0` to your `NA` to get the max the way you consider it, then reassign `NA` to `0` at the end.
- You are missing two values in your data and I considered them to be `NA`.

Comment: Okay! That all makes sense to me and was what I was thinking, though I didn't know about the max function with NA.  Thanks for the explanation!